# org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known

Tags: java, hibernate

Al invocar una consulta con nombre especifica el sistema lanza la excepción: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known`. Le he dado varias vueltas pero no consigo encontrar donde está el problema.

**Consumo.java**

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "consumo" )
@NamedQueries( {
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "Consumo.findConsumoPasoHistorico",
                query = "SELECT c FROM Consumo c WHERE c.fecha < :fechaTope ORDER BY c.fecha, c.id" )
} )
public class Consumo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Basic( optional = false )
    @Column( name = "id" )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private Long id;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    @Column( name = "fecha" )
    private Date fecha;

    @Column( name = "valor" )
    private double valor;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    @Column( name = "created" )
    private Date created;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    @Column( name = "updated" )
    private Date updated;

    //Getters y setters
}
```

El método desde el que invoco la función:

```
public List<Consumo> findConsumoPasoHistorico(Date fechaTope) {
    Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("Consumo.findConsumoPasoHistorico");
    query.setParameter("fechaTope", fechaTope);
    return query.list();
}
```

Me he cerciorado de que el fichero de configuración `hibernate.cfg.xml` contenga la referencia para mapear la clase Consumo:

```
<mapping class="es.kestrel.monitorizador.modelo.Consumo"/>
```

Comment: Nunca habia visto esta forma de hacer una query en hbm, no es más eficiente utilizar criterias y criteriones, para este tipo de consultas basicas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata cambiando la parte señalada, ya que no necesitas indicar la clase:

```
public List<Consumo> findConsumoPasoHistorico(Date fechaTope) {
    //Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("Consumo.findConsumoPasoHistorico");
    Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("findConsumoPasoHistorico");
    query.setParameter("fechaTope", fechaTope);
    return query.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo normalmente las llamo mediante el método `createNamedQuery` del `Entity Manager`.

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Consumo.findConsumoPasoHistorico", Consumo.class);
List resultados = query.getResultList();
```

Para más información puedes consultar http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named.